# Todo list and/or Kanban tool

Tags: gratis, open-source, todo, kanban

I'm looking for a to-do list and/or Kanban tool.  I came across Kanban while looking up to-do list managers here and think that might be a good fit.  I'm not really sure what I need as far as a task manager, but as far as the technical details of the software, I have a good idea on that.

### Must have features

- Task management
- Not cloud based
- Windows program
- Android App
- P2P or server based syncing (either natively or connected to a FLOSS file sych tool)
- Free or 1 time cost
- Reputable software dev or company

### Optional / nice to haves

- Calendar integration
- Locally hosted web app like on a Raspberry Pi
- Notes
- Encrypted storage
- FLOSS
- nextCloud integration

Comment: I'm leaving for the weeknd, with along drive ahead, so don't have time to post a proper answer, however, what you want it JetBrains' YouTrack. Try it & tell me that you agree :-)

Comment: @Mawg That software is a wep app.  That means it's cloud based.  That's a major disadvantage and deal breaker.

Comment: I run it on my laptop, using [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) for `http://localhost` Can't you locally host it also?

Comment: It's not clear how I go from a sign up page to a locally hosted instance of it, so if you could post a proper answer, I might be able to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the comment grew too large, so I am posting as an answer, but I can assure you that YouTrack will meet your needs.

You will need a server to run it on your own machine. Maybe you already have Apache or IIS? If not, install [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Start Xampp/Apache before installing YouTrack. If you don't, it will grab port 80, which will prevent Xampp form using it later. If this does happen, you can change the YouTrack port number as described on [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Change-Port-YouTrack-Windows-Service.html) (don't worry, if you don't quite understand that; just start them in the correct order & you will be fine)

The YouTrack documentation is excellent.  Follow [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/youtrack-msi.html) - I recommend the .MSI installation, rather than .JAR or .ZIP. Be sure to choose local installation, if requested and double check that the port number is not 80.

That installation only needs to be done once & after that it is straightforward.  Just create a new project and choose "kanban" ...

The [kanban documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Set-up-a-Kanban-Board.html) is comprehensive. Enjoy!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: You coudl also host it on a Rapsbery Pi